# Access <li> elements inside HTML

Tags: html, swift, parsing, xpath

I am trying to parse HTML in my Swift project but I am stuck.

I am trying to access  info inside of the `<li>`, for example:

```
li source="page/external" size="3.244 Mb" rate="128 Kb/s" link="13770751aJE0" song="On The Run (MOUNT Remix)" singer="Kytes" file_id="3ddqom328a" duration="212"
```

How would I access the info like size in Swift?

I am using Kanna. My XPath currently is:

```
"/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ol/li"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the attribute axis, like:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ol/li/@size
```